# Vagrant: Shell Provisioner operation in a multi-machine environment

Tags: shell

I am building a multi-machine environment and am puzzling over the behaviour I am seeing as the Vagrantfile is processed.

My goal:
Create n number of virtual machines with 3 different roles.   All n VMs will use a common "bootstrap.sh" script then each role will run another script based on the hostname/role.

The Vagrantfile is here:
[Vagrantfile](https://github.com/kvietmeier/vagrant/blob/master/virtualbox/Ceph/)

All the individual pieces/sections work, the scripts run and the extra disks are created in the correct VMs and in the correct number.   What I am trying to understand is why the "inline" provisioner behaves differently how to make sure the role specific scripts run at the correct time.

First question - why does this code only execute once?

```
      config.vm.provision "Setup shell environment", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      # Install some tools
      #yum install -y net-tools traceroute git ansible gcc make python > /dev/null 2>&1 
      # Add the public key
      mkdir /root/.ssh
      chmod 700 /root/.ssh
      touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo "Appending user@Laptop keys to root and vagrant authorized_keys"
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo "Appending AdminVM keys to root and vagrant authorized_keys"
      echo #{adminvm_karlvkey} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{adminvm_karlvkey} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{adminvm_rootkey} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{adminvm_rootkey} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

      # Copy /etc/hosts
      #if [ -e /vagrant/files/hosts ]
      #  then sudo cat /vagrant/files/hosts >> /etc/hosts
      #elif [ -e /home/vagrant/sync/files/hosts ]
      #  then sudo cat /home/vagrant/sync/files/hosts >> /etc/hosts
      #fi     
    SHELL
  end # inline shell provisioner config.provision
```

But this execute once for each element in the hash that has been parsed?  So for the first VM in the hash, "admin" everything works correctly.  But in subsequent iterations it runs once for every preceding element?  So by the sixth VM it is running six times.

```
 config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "../../scripts/bash/config/bootstrap.sh"
```

Same for these:

```
  # - OSD Node
  if ("#{servers["name"]}").include? "osd"
    puts "I'm an OSD"
    puts servers["name"]
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "../../scripts/bash/ceph/osd.sh"
  end
```

I suspect I am failing to grok some basic principle here.   I looked all over the internet, even got right up to the edge of the internet and couldn't find a good explanation.

Comment: I partially answered my own question.   Like most answsers once you have them it is fairly obvious I just couldn't find a good example of how to do this anywhere I looked.  You need to terminate the config.vm.provision line with an "end".

Answer (score 0):

This stops the bootscrap.sh script from running multple times:

```
  config.vm.provision "bootstrap", type: "shell" do |script|
     script.path = "../../scripts/bash/config/bootstrap.sh"
  end
```

I still can't figure out how to get these to stop from executing.   I think I understand why they will get excecuted every time, just not sure how to stop it.  They need to run only for that VM being configured and after the bootstrap scripts.   I can't be the only person who has ever wanted to do this, I just can't find it documented anywhere.

```
  if ("#{servers["name"]}").include? "osd"
    config.vm.provision "Configure OSD Node", type: "shell" do |script|
       script.path = "../../scripts/bash/ceph/osd.sh"
    end
  end

  # - Monitor Node
  if ("#{servers["name"]}").include? "mon"
    config.vm.provision "Configure Monitor Node", type: "shell" do |script|
       script.path = "../../scripts/bash/ceph/monitor.sh"
    end
  end

  # - Admin Node
  if ("#{servers["name"]}").include? "admin"
    config.vm.provision "Configure Admin Node", type: "shell" do |script|
       script.path = "../../scripts/bash/ceph/admin.sh"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution:

```
  ### External shell scripts for configuration
  # - Run on every node
  config.vm.provision "bootstrap", type: "shell" do |script|
     script.path = "../../scripts/bash/config/bootstrap.sh"
  end

  # Role based setup is in the servers.yml file - pull it out as a key:value
  config.vm.provision "Role", type: "shell" do |script|
     script.path = "../../scripts/bash/ceph/#{servers["script"]}"
  end
```

I have a "servers.yml" file that I added another property of the VM to, "script".   I then just call it explicitly in script.path.

Everything is working perfectly now and my Vagrantfile is updated.